# Select All Employees that rendered 2 years in service using datediff

Tags: vb.net

i need to select all the employees who already rendered 2 years in service from their date of employment . at first i thought my code was working.because the data was generated when i set the year of employment of a specific employee from feb 9 2017. but when i changed it from feb 9 to feb 10. the data is still generating.

**Code**

```
 select Date_of_employment,FirstName,LastName from MemInfo WHERE datediff(YEAR,Date_of_Employment,getdate())=2
```

Comment: You might want to show your data classes and more code so people can answer you better.

Comment: owh it's working. i just changed the YEAR to DAY to get the exact DATE

Comment: Lol, I've entered the 'Twilight Zone'

Comment: You will still get two years because the difference is only a day.

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/date-and-time-data-types-and-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#GetDateandTimeDifference)

> DATEDIFF Returns the number of date or time datepart boundaries,
>   crossed between two specified dates.

So, (psuedo code) DATEDIFF(year, 12/31/2018, 1/1/2019) would return 1 because one year boundary was crossed.

You might get better results with `DATEADD (datepart , number , date )`

```
select Date_of_employment,FirstName,LastName from MemInfo WHERE DATEADD(year, Date_of_employment, 2) > GETDATE();
```